# Disable particular row in JTable using data from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I was wondering if it's possible to **grey out** or render some rows in my JTable to be **invisible** using the data from my data base?

These are the columns in my JTable:

```
public DutyModel(ArrayList<Duty> listOfObjects) {
        rowCount = listOfObjects.size();
        colCount = columnNames.length;
        data = new Object[rowCount][colCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            /* Copy an ArrayList element to an instance of MyObject */
            Duty d1 = (Duty) (listOfObjects.get(i));

            data[i][0] = d1.getDutyId();
            data[i][1] = d1.getDutyName();
            data[i][2] = d1.getDutyDesc();
            data[i][3] = d1.getDutySectorName();
            data[i][4] = d1.getDutyStatus();
        }
    }
```

When my table is displayed, I want the rows with d1.getDutyStatus() where dutyStatus = "Inactive" to be greyed out. My table can currently be updated to either "Active" (By pressing an update button), or "Inactive" (By pressing a remove button). I don't want the user to be able to edit any of the duties that have the dutyStatus of "Inactive". Any assistance or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The below code is what happens when the user selects a row in the JTable and presses the "Update" and "Delete" button. **Also**, I'm trying to use a 3 tier architecture to run my codes, my controller class is RetrieveDutyControl and my entity is Duty.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int rowSelected = tblDutyList.getSelectedRow();
            if (rowSelected >= 0) {
                String idDuty = tblDutyList.getValueAt(rowSelected, 0)
                        .toString();
                String name = tblDutyList.getValueAt(rowSelected, 1)
                        .toString();
                String desc = tblDutyList.getValueAt(rowSelected, 2)
                        .toString();
                String sector = tblDutyList.getValueAt(rowSelected, 3)
                        .toString();
                String status = tblDutyList.getValueAt(rowSelected, 4)
                        .toString();
                Duty duty = new Duty(Integer.parseInt(idDuty), name, desc,
                        sector, status);
                RetrieveDutyControl rdc = new RetrieveDutyControl();
                ArrayList<Duty> dutyList = rdc.processRetrieveDuties(duty);

                JPanel contentPane = new RemoveDutyForm(myFrame, duty);
                myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Selected",
                        "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

Comment: You have to look in to custom cell rendering. check on  this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/336608/GUI/java/disabling-rows-JTable

Comment: Alright, I'll go try it out! Thank you for your help! :-) @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with overridden `prepareRenderer()` method to gray out the row based on data

Sample code: (use first column's value to validate)

```
Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
Object[][] data = { 
        { "abc", new Double(850.503), 53, true },
        { "lmn", new Double(36.23254), 6, false }, 
        { "pqr", new Double(8.3), 7, false },
        { "xyz", new Double(246.0943), 23, true } };

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public java.awt.Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        java.awt.Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
        if (value.equals("lmn")) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        }  else {
           comp.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

[image]

---

For buttons check for value and do nothing.

How to get the value of the selected row?

```
if(table.getSelectedRow()!=-1){
    int rowIndex=table.getSelectedRow();
    Object value=table.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
    if(value.equals("lmn")){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        // perform desired operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I managed to get the button part of the code to disable selection of the inactive rows. However I'd like to ask how should I customize the color of the row if my table model is in a separate class? Like my attributes "columnNames" and "data" is not in the same class as my Jtable?

P.S Thank you, your answer was really helpful! :-)

Comment: no worries if you have the reference of the `table` then you can get it using `table.getModel()`.